# Compilation error "incompatible types" in a Java class named String

Tags: java, string

Error in String....

My error:

```
C:\Users\Kiran\Desktop\java\bin>javac String.java  
String.java:7: error: incompatible types  
String text = "Hello";  
              ^  
  required: String
  found:    java.lang.String  
String.java:9: error: incompatible types  
String blank = " ";  
               ^
  required: String  
  found:    java.lang.String  
String.java:11: error: incompatible types  
String name = "Kiran";  
              ^  
  required: String  
  found:    java.lang.String    
String.java:13: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'  
String message = text + blank + name;   
                      ^
  first type:  String  
  second type: String  
4 errors
```

My program:

```
public class String {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int myNumber = 7;
        String text = "Hello";
        String blank = " ";
        String name = "Kiran";
        String message = text + blank + name;
        System.out.println(message);
        System.out.println("Hello Java" + " " + "Iam Kiran");
        System.out.println("my integer is : " +myNumber);
        double myDouble = 7.8;
        System.out.println("my number is: " + myDouble + "!!");
    }
}
```

I don't know why this error coming. I wrote approximately Right. But it still keeps coming.
My java program is in Desktop.

Comment: Your class name shouldn't be `String`, otherwise you are overriding the original `java.lang.String`.

Comment: Change your class name to some thing else and not "String", to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't name your class `String`. That shadows `java.lang.String`, and then (as you discovered) it is very difficult to use the other `String`.

```
// You could still use
java.lang.String text = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your Class or use fully qualified name wherever you are using `java.lang.String`

When you name your class as `String` and you try to use

```
String s="abc";
```

you get compile time errors because you think you are using `java.lang.String` but in fact you just make a reference of your own class

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your java class and don't use **String** as a name.

Answer (score 0):

String is a predefined class in java to represent the sequence of characters (ofcourse there are lot more benefits).  When you use String as you class name, it is masking the original java String implementation.  So compiler is expecting the String class that was written by you to handle the initialization, appending etc.,

You could solve this in following ways:
1) User fully qualified name like java.lang.String text = "Hello"; where ever you are using actual java implementation of String
2) Rename you class, say String to MyString etc,